# If A and B stands in a circle with 10 other persons ,then find the number of ways in which there are 3 persons between A and B?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

How to solve this problem in easy way to understand ,and tell me." If A and B stands in a circle with 10 other persons ,then find the number of ways in which there are 3 persons between A and B?"

Answer (score 2):

$\underline{Another\; hint}$

- Place **A** at the $12$ o'clock position
- **B** now has $2$ possible places.
- The remaining $10$ can be permuted in vacant places in how many ways ?

---

**Added**

$\underline{Solution\;using\;the\;above\;hint}$

In such problems, unless otherwise specified, the circle is always taken as unnumbered.
It is convenient here to assume that the people are placed at the hour hands

- Place **A** at the $12$ o'clock position, thus creating a reference point for the others
- **B** can now  be placed in two ways ( at $8$ o'clock or $4$ o'clock position)
- The vacant slots can now be filled in $10!$ ways

Thus ans $= 2*10!$

---

$\underline{Your\; attempted\; answer\;\ corrected}$

You have **selected** $3$ persons using $\binom{10}3$ but you haven't **permuted** them,
thus corrected answer $= 7!2!\binom{10}33!$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Place $A$ and $B$ on the circle and "reserve" 3 places on one side of them and 7 more on the other side. Now try to fill the places one by one and see how many possibilities for each place you have

**UPDATE:** Another way to solve this problem is to first order the 10 people in a circle, then choose a position for A and at the end do the same for B, keeping in mind that there should be 3 people between them

Comment: Now I got the answer 7!×2!×10c3 is it correct or not

Comment: Not yet correct.

Comment: Tell me perfect solution

Comment: I have now expanded the hint into an answer

Comment: @PoralVinay it's impolite to ask for people to solve problems you've posted. All of the users are volunteering here and you don't have a right to order them. Also this is not a homework or problem solving site, it's a site where people help other learn. When posting a problem you should also post your attempted solution and people will be more willing to help you in the area where you have problems. Also not many of the users will post complete solutions to the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Start with a circle that gives place for $12$ persons, and let $A$ possess one of these spots allready.

Now place $B$ and be aware that there are $2$ spots available for him.

Now place the others.